# How to stop grep matching in terminal escape sequences (or colorize to multiple colours)?

Tags: grep, linux-terminal, escape-sequences

I've written a bunch of scripts to colorize matches, like this:

```
$ echo abcdef | grepg c
ab[green]c[/green]def
$ echo abcdef | grepr e
abcd[red]e[/red]f
```

It also works when I chain it:

```
$ echo abcef | grepr a | grepg b | grepg c | grepp e | grepl f
abcdef   [each letter have it's own style]
```

Hovewer when I try this for digits, the result is wrong:

```
$ echo 12345 | grepr 1 | grepg 2 | grepb 3 | grepp 4 | grepl 5
[01;[01;3[01;35m4m31m1[01;[01;3[01;35m4m32m2[01;3[01;35m4m3[01;35m45
```

because if subsequent greps also match inside the escape sequences produced by earlier greps.

How to do it right? I need either to stop grep matching inside terminal escale sequences or make it match more than one pattern and colorize them to different colours.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [lookkbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and lookahead in regexes.

Something like

```
(?<!\[\d\d;\d\d?m)yourregexhere
```

could work (I'm not sure about the format of the colorizing strings)